# Testfor items in hopper 1.12.2!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a system I need a hopper check and check which type of wool is inside the hopper so I tried this: (I execute the command in chat while I was standing on top of the hopper)

```
/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:hopper -1 {Items: 
{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:wool",Count:1b,Damage:0s}}
```

Output:

> The Block at 3 50 20 did not have the required NBT keys

So I looked on internet but it still didn't work, so can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? I need help with the DataTag, but if anything else is wrong tell me.

[image: Inside the hopper...]

Comment: But you're also not an expert. I can see this because you use `/testfor`. ;)

Comment: /testforblock and lol i'm a command expert you should see some of my build haha you'll change your mind ;P

Comment: Do you use comparators or restone dust in them?

Comment: normally not I also 've create a switch and other statements commandblocks so i actually dont use redstone i can use /blockdata

Comment: You could put a link to your Minecraft forum profile or other website into your profile. That way we don't talk too much offtopic in the comments (what they are not made for).

Comment: Just to note it, if you omit the Slot argument from the data tag, it will check all of the slots instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is really unintuitive, because what it should tell you is that the NBT has a syntax error. `Items` is an array tag, so you need `[]`:

```
/testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:hopper -1 {Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:wool",Count:1b,Damage:0s}]}
```

Comment: omg yes i forgot them -_-

Comment: THX lol i use them all the time, the best can make stupid mistakes ;PPP

Comment: I mean, it's not really a syntax error. What he entered is perfectly valid NBT, it's just not the *right* NBT.